# I always get "something is already running on port 3000" whenever I do npm start on react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, port

Today I was trying to create a fake rest api with express js and deployed my api to heroku
I am so new to this and followed the youtube video.
And in the app.js file i typed below

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("server is working")
})
```

but now whenever i create a new react app and run npm start, i get "something is already running on port 3000" error.
I tried below solutions from what i searched but none of these worked. I use WINDOWS 10 as my operating system.

1. I changed the port from 3000 to 4200 in the express.js and pushed it however did not change.
2. i ended the task from task manager for node.js-server-javascript and did not work
3. i tried npx kill-port 300 and did not work ( it says the command kill-port is not found )
4. i opened command line as administrator and typed below commands

```
netstat -a -o -n
taskkill /F /PID PID_of_port
```

```
netstat -ano | find "3000"
taskkill -f -pid 27692
```

But i get below error although I opened the command line as administrator

ERROR: The process with PID 27692 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access denied.

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe process 27692 is a zombie process of sorts. What do you see when you look for that PID in task manager? Try restarting your computer.

Comment: the process of 3000 is LISTENING. i ll try restarting my computer

Comment: (This isn't what I meant, I meant when you look for the process in task manager's details page.)

Comment: ohh i m sorry, i did not know this. but restarting my computer worked Lol :D i have been trying for hours and tried every single solution on stackoverflow :D thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe running your back end first. When you want run back and front end simultaneously, first you have to run front end which will call your back end. and use both on different servers

Comment: yeah but i closed the backend server. i dont want to use them together. i needed a new react app unrelated to the backend server. and i get this error.

Comment: restart your laptop/computer and your server should be free:)

Comment: yeah that worked omg :D i ve been trying for hours with every solution. thanks a lot :)

Comment: hahah :D no issues